# How to add field content as class in Twig?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to add the content of a field (i.e. "workshop") as a class in field-html.twig

i tried

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    'icon-' ~ item.content,
  ]
%}
```

but it only shows "icon-" as a class.

Comment: You know when you enable Devel's submodule Kint you can put `{{ kint() }}` to inspect variables onpage?

Answer (score 1):

`item.content` works only in the items loop, but don't try to put rendered output in a class name. Use the field value instead, which you can get through the field object `#items` stored in a field template inside of the variable `element`:

```
{{ element['#items'].value }}
```

or from a different field of the parent entity:

```
{{ element['#object'].field_example.value }}
```

Depending on the field type replace `.value` with a different property, for example for a reference field to get the target id or the label of the target with `.target_id` or `.entity.label`.

When you have found the field value build your class name:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    ...
    'icon-' ~ element['#items'].value|clean_class,
  ]
%}
```

Comment: and how should i add this as a class?

Comment: replace the rendered output `item.content` with the field value: `'icon-' ~ element['#items'].value|clean_class,`

Comment: thank you, but is gives "icon-array"

Comment: You didn't provide any details what field type this is. Can you provide a kint output of the variable to see what is in it?

Comment: it’s a taxonomy reference field. i’ll try give asap a kint output. thx.